# ATmega2560 freeze on start up

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, power-supply

My arduino mega freezes on startup.  I am powering it with an ATX power supply and the Arduino does nothing after power is applied, until I hit the reset button.  I thought the issue was the slow startup but I measured the Power-On Slope Rate to be about 0.56 V/ms which is slow but still well above the minimum 0.01 V/ms for the ATmega2560.

I figured the issue might be the Brown-out Detect threshold, so I used an AVR programmer to change the fuse settings.  I tried 1.8V, 2.7V, and 4.3V BOD thresholds but none of them fix the problem.  Even if it were the BOD, I figure the microcontroller should eventually come out of reset mode.

My first question is: how could I modify the arduino mega board so it will startup reliably?  Is there some capacitance or a resistor I could add to help the microcontroller startup reliably?  **Note**: using the POK signal is not an option.

Second: if I need to increase the Power-On Slope Rate, what is a method to do this without modifying the power supply?

Comment: Did you try using a voltage supervisor?

Comment: After you press reset, the part works as expected?!

Comment: You may want to also check your clock related fuses `CKSELx` and `SUTx`.

Comment: Ignacio answered my second question. I believe Hanno helped with my first. I messed with CKSEL and SUT like Hanno suggested and, after bricking and recovering the chip several times, I think I figured it out. I'm not sure why, but the SUT delay doesn't seem to be working with my configuration. So, I reduced the SUT to 1k clock cycles + 0ms of extra delay and turned BOD up to 4.3V. Now my settings are SUT_CKSEL = EXTXOSC_8MHZ_XX_1KCK_0MS and BODLEVEL = 4V3. The chip has booted up every time since.